# pyodbc and xmp toolkit adding metadata printing on command line but only adding first letter in metadata

Tags: python-2.7, pyodbc, xmp

Hi I'm having a problem adding metadata to some jpg images.

I am querying a filemaker database via pyodbc

```
sql = cur.execute("""SELECT division, attribute_20, brand_name FROM table WHERE item_number=?""", (prod))
row = cur.fetchone()
```

when I `print(row[0])` i get an output of 'BRN' and the type is 'unicode'

However when I try too add this as metadata `xmp.set_property(consts.XMP_NS_DC, u'DivisionName', row[0])`

it only inputs the first letter. `<dc:DivisionName>B</dc:DivisionName>`

I have tried converting this to a string but it's the same problem.

Any help would be really appreciated!

Richard